# SDL_mixer audio problem

Tags: 20.04, sdl

When I try to initialize SDL_mixer sound

```c
if (Mix_OpenAudio(MIX_DEFAULT_FREQUENCY, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0)
{
    printf("SDL_mixer could not initialize! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
    success = false;
}
```

The following error appears:

```
SDL_mixer Error: 
    No such audio device
```

The compiler is `GCC` and the operating system is `Ubuntu 20.04`.

What can be the solution to this error?

Answer (score 0):

First install `libasound2-dev` and `libpulse-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev libpulse-dev
```

Then build SDL again. So configure script find the new headers so it includes PulseAudio and ALSA support.

https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/couldnt-open-audio-device-no-available-audio-device/18499

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the corresponding dependencies, as shown in the doc:
https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-linux.md

Ubuntu 18.04, all available features enabled:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential git make \
pkg-config cmake ninja-build gnome-desktop-testing libasound2-dev libpulse-dev \
libaudio-dev libjack-dev libsndio-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev \
libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxss-dev \
libxkbcommon-dev libdrm-dev libgbm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev \
libegl1-mesa-dev libdbus-1-dev libibus-1.0-dev libudev-dev fcitx-libs-dev
```

Then build the source code. For the construction method, please refer to the link below:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Installation

```bash
git clone git@github.com:libsdl-org/SDL.git -b SDL2 --recurse-submodules
cd SDL
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```